# Only see one mesh object out of 16 on ThreeJS canvas?

Tags: three.js, position

I have a ThreeJS scene with 16 objects that are supposed to end up in a 4 by 4 square grid.  However, when I run the code, I only see one of the objects.  I wrote a "dump" function to show me all the current XYZ values of the mesh objects's **position** property, which you can see below.  The values all look good to me and I believe I should see a nice 4 by 4 square grid of objects given the positioning those values present.

I am using this ThreeJS Javascript file for ThreeJS:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js
```

I am using this code to create the mesh.  The mesh is a cube with initially the side facing the camera is a cat image:

```
function makeCatCube(catImageUrl, textureBackSide, locX, locY, locZ) {
    let errPrefix = '(makeCatCube) ';

    // TODO: Should we use BoxBufferGeometry here for greater speed?
    let cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 0.1, 2);
    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    let materialArray = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        // Card face.
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load(catImageUrl) } ),
        // Card back side.
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
            {
                map: textureBackSide
            }
        ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load('/images/cards/white-square-400x400.png') } ),
    ];

    cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, materialArray );

    if (g_ShowGraphicsDebugInfo) {
        console.log(errPrefix + `Setting cube position to - X: ${locX}, Y: ${locY}, Z: ${locZ}`);
    }

    cube.position.set(locX, locZ, locY);
    // TODO: Magic number to set the cube's X rotation so it looks flat facing the viewer.
    cube.rotation.x = THREE.Math.radToDeg(60);
    return cube;
}
```

Here is the main promise that builds all the game assets and shows where I add the mesh objects to the scene.  The global *g_aryCatCards* array that contains all the cat cards that were built is prepared in a much larger module elsewhere.  It contains each of the cat cards and each card has a *meshThreeJS* property that contains the ThreeJS mesh object (i.e. - the cube) that was built using the *makeCatCube()* function shown above :

```
function initializeGameAssets_promise(gameAreaDomElementID, threeJSCanvasAreaDomElementID, catCardWidth, catCardHeight) {
    let errPrefix = '(initializeGameAssets_promise) ';

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            buildAllCatCards_promise(gameAreaDomElementID, threeJSCanvasAreaDomElementID, 1, catCardWidth, catCardHeight)
            .then(result => {
                g_Scene = new THREE.Scene();
                g_Scene.background = new THREE.Color('yellow');

                initCamera();
                initRenderer();

                for (let cardLabelKey in g_aryCatCards) {
                    let catCard = g_aryCatCards[cardLabelKey];
                    g_Scene.add(catCard.meshThreeJS);
                }

                let threeJSCanvasAreaDOMElement = document.getElementById(threeJSCanvasAreaDomElementID);
                if (!threeJSCanvasAreaDOMElement)
                    throw new Error(errPrefix + `Unable to find the DOM element for the cat cards underlay table using ID: ${threeJSCanvasAreaDomElementID}`);

                threeJSCanvasAreaDOMElement.appendChild(g_Renderer.domElement);

                let catCardsTableElementOffset = getElementOffsetById(ELEMENT_ID_CAT_CARDS_TABLE);
                threeJSCanvasAreaDOMElement.left = catCardsTableElementOffset.left;
                threeJSCanvasAreaDOMElement.top = catCardsTableElementOffset.top;

                // Start the rendering process.
                render();

                resolve(true);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });
        }
        catch(err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Here are the functions I use to initialize the camera and the renderer:

```
function initCamera() {
    g_Camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
    g_Camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
    g_Camera.lookAt(g_Scene.position);
}

function initRenderer() {
    g_Renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(
    {
        antialias: true
    });
}
```

This dump shows the XYZ values of the mesh object's *position* property:

```
------------- DUMPING MESH POSITIONS -------------
[label: A1] - X: 2, Y: 0, Z: 2
[label: A2] - X: 176, Y: 0, Z: 2
[label: A3] - X: 350, Y: 0, Z: 2
[label: A4] - X: 525, Y: 0, Z: 2
[label: E1] - X: 2, Y: 0, Z: 364
[label: E2] - X: 176, Y: 0, Z: 364
[label: E3] - X: 350, Y: 0, Z: 364
[label: E4] - X: 525, Y: 0, Z: 364
[label: L1] - X: 2, Y: 0, Z: 183
[label: L2] - X: 176, Y: 0, Z: 183
[label: L3] - X: 350, Y: 0, Z: 183
[label: L4] - X: 525, Y: 0, Z: 183
[label: X1] - X: 2, Y: 0, Z: 545
[label: X2] - X: 176, Y: 0, Z: 545
[label: X3] - X: 350, Y: 0, Z: 545
[label: X4] - X: 525, Y: 0, Z: 545
```

I really don't know what to do at this point to debug this problem.  Can anyone give me some general tips on what to inspect, or what diagnostic code I could write to try and figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Your camera can only see 9 units deep

```
new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
```

but your objects are up to 545 units away

Try

```
const near = 1;
const far = 1000;
new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, near, far);
```

[see](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-cameras.html)

You also seem to have the camera looking in the wrong direction.

```
g_Camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
g_Camera.lookAt(g_Scene.position);
```

AFAIK g_scene.position is 0, 0, 0 which means the camera is at z = 5 looking toward Z = 0 but your list of objects are almost all behind the camera.

Try

```
g_Camera.position.set(0, 3.5, -50);
g_Camera.lookAt(g_Scene.position);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just gave that  exact code a try but I did not see any difference when I reran the app.

Comment: Your suggestion has shown me that my entire scene/camera orientation is all screwed up.  Although things still didn't look right after trying your suggestion, I did fnally see the other squares far, far in the distance with the one square huge in comparison.  So I guess the camera is very close to the visible square and VERY far from the others.  As a result, I added OrbitControls using them I could reorient the scene until things looked right.  I'm not sure yet what I'm doing wrong overall in my approach, but at least now I know what *is* wrong and where to look.

Comment: As you can also see I add a "magic" (60) number to the  cube rotation X value to make it look "flat" to the camera since by default (in my screwed up setup) it looks very tilted.  I'm just adding this to confirm I am doing something very wrong in my camera/scene initialization.  I've got a lot of work and reading to do.  Thanks.